# IE prints blank pages from CSS Boilerplate

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

My company is using a print.css for printing. Also, we have another style.css that overrides any other .css files including print.css. For some reason, IE8 and IE9 are printing blank pages when the @media print query from html5 boilerplate (which is in the override file) is on. When it's commented out, there are no problems. What is the issue here? We would like to leave in the @media print from boilerplate.

PRINT.CSS

```
@media print
{
body *
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#basicShell #main,
#basicShell #main *,
.basicShell_container .content,
.basicShell_container .content *,
#mainShell_container .center_columnContent,
#mainShell_container .center_columnContent *
{
    visibility:visible;
}

#basicShell #main,
.basicShell_container .content,
#mainShell_container .center_columnContent
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
}
```

STYLE.CSS (overrides everything)

```
@media print {
* { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; text-shadow: none    
!important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important; float: none 
!important;} /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
.ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }  /*  
Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
thead { display: table-header-group; } /* h5bp.com/t */
tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
img { max-width: 100% !important; }
@page { margin: 0.5cm; }
p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
h2, h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue with the HTML5 Boilerplate.

In my case, it turned out to be this line:

```
tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

that caused the blank pages in IE8/9.  The page had a large amount of content in a  tag (more than one page's worth), and IE decided to handle it by skipping a page and cutting off the content.  Yuck.

To avoid messing with the HTML5 Boilerplate, I added the following to my own stylesheet, and problem solved:

```
tr { page-break-inside: auto; }
```

Your issue may be due to a different tag, so check anything that sets the page-break-inside property.

Comment: I had the same issue with bootstrap 3.3. This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

The first rule in print.css makes all subelements of `body` invisible. The intent appears to be to turn some elements to visible, but apparently this fails, perhaps because the markup (which was not disclosed) does not use `id` and `class` attributes in the intended way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the precedence of the stylesheets being loaded in your site. Currently you have this stated on the `print.css` stylesheet:

```
body * {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

That rule basically hides "everything" inside the document. You mentioned that the `styles.css` stylesheet is supposed to override everything, but in what order are the stylesheets being loaded in your header? If the print.css sheet is after the style.css sheet then the rules of the first with be taken into place.

There is also the case of the `media` types included in your link reference, which i don't know which has better precedence; the link media type, or media query.

Comment: Also, why is that rule even being used? You can just delete it and everything will be well.

Comment: That rule hides everything so that you can then show only certain elements (e.g., don't want to show select lists in print).